# Not quite vested in a defined-benefit plan

Tags: united-states, retirement-plan

Another question on this stack made me curious about this:

From 1999 to 2003 I worked at an unpleasant place.  The retirement plan was a defined benefit plan in which one was vested after 5 years.  As you can see, I was there 4 years.  I made no contributions to the plan.

However, in the answers or comments to that other question, someone said that it was illegal if one was not "partially vested" after 4 years.  This other question was about a 401k, so the rules and laws would be different and probably differ by state.

This unpleasant job was in Texas, but the company HQ is in St. Louis.  The retirement plan is internal to the company. They own it and administer it.

So the question is:  Is there a decent possibility that I own part of the benefit for which my employer paid over 4 years?  It's always rankled me that I lost all that benefit by not staying an extra year.  (The place was driving me insane and I knew at the time that I was losing 4 years of retirement savings.  And I still chose to leave.)  Still...?

Comment: Was there a vesting schedule?  (Maybe you got a partial pension after four years.)

Comment: @RonJohn  I was told verbally that I "would lose everything" while I was packing up, but I never saw a vesting schedule.  My question is whether it is legal to not have a vesting schedule.  That "other question" made me wonder this.

Comment: The vesting schedule was "100% after 5 years".

Comment: @RonJohn  I believe that and I believed it at the time.  Because of the other question, (and because of record of gross bumbling by these people) I thought perhaps there was a law against such a schedule.  I'm looking for some Schadenfreude here ;-)

Comment: The people you spoke to at the time might have lied to you from anger, etc but thing of it this way: **you** are the employer; why should you have to give a **defined benefit** pension **for their whole retired life** to someone who worked for you a measly four years.  That's completely different from **defined contribution**, which is essentially just a pay raise.

Comment: @RonJohn  "Why should you give someone a defined benefit" for only 4 years.  I wouldn't expect it to be the same as if I had worked there 40 years.  There's some formula based on last 3 or 5 years average salary and years worked.  So the pension would be small, but I did, really, earn it.  And another answer to the same question, "Why should they do it for a measly 5 years?"  Whatever I would have gotten for 5 years, I'd like 80% of.  And thanks for your attention and conversation, btw.

Comment: *Whatever I would have gotten for 5 years, I'd like 80% of.*  Think of how much extra expense that adds.  And the people who worked there 3 years want 60%, and the people who worked there 3 months want 5% **for their entire retired lives**.

Comment: (This is why I think company-sponsored defined benefits are a bad idea.  Defined contributions are the way to go.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to say 'no'.

My answer is based on personal experience, a fortune 500 company that discontinued its defined benefit plan. Those of us with over 4 years on the date of termination had two choices, a frozen annuity value, i.e. they offered a projection of the future benefit, but no new deposits, a number that would not grow, or, a lump sum to an IRA account as a rollover.

There were 2 employees out of the 30 or so in our local office who realised they were 2 months shy of the date. They got zero. FWIW, the year this occurred was 2004. No idea if the laws changed to make this illegal. (but you quit in 2003....)